# How can I skip past the explosive charges part of 'The Local Flavour' in Fallout 3: Point Lookout?

Tags: fallout-3

For *The Local Flavor* quest of Point Lookout, the first explosive barrel did not spawn correctly, so I can't cover the breach.

Is there any command to skip past this part or another way to fix the quest to advance?

Comment: Are you on Console or PC?

Comment: Your best bet is to probably load an old save (if you  can) before you triggered this event, leave the DLC area, then come back. This should reload the necessary area